# How to get nth column with regexp delimiter

Tags: bash, unix, text, text-processing

Basically I get line from `ls -la` command:

```
-rw-r--r--  13 ondrejodchazel  staff  442 Dec 10 16:23 some_file
```

and want to get size of file (442). I have tried `cut` and `sed` commands, but was unsuccesfull. Using just basic UNIX tools (cut, sed, awk...), how can i get specific column from stdin, where delimiter is `/ +/` regexp?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to do it with `cut` you need to squeeze the space first (`tr -s ' '`) because `cut` doesn't support `+`. This should work:

```
ls -la | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f 5
```

It's a bit more work when doing it with `sed` (GNU sed):

```
ls -la | sed -r 's/([^ ]+ +){4}([^ ]+).*/\2/'
```

Slightly more finger punching if you use the grep alternative (GNU grep):

```
ls -la | grep -Eo '[^ ]+( +[^ ]+){4}' | grep -Eo '[^ ]+$'
```

Comment: +1 for 'sed | cut' flow. By far the most flexible, powerful, concise technique for column grokking.

Answer (score 5):

Parsing `ls` output is harder than you think. Use a dedicated tool such as `stat` instead.

```
size=$(stat -c '%s' some_file)
```

One way `ls -la some_file | awk '{print $5}'` could break is if numbers use space as a thousands separator (this is common in some European locales).

See also [Why You Shouldn't Parse the Output of *ls*(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Thanks, your answer is good, but parsing ls output was rather example of usage, then the real usage.

Answer (score 2):

Pipe your output with:

```
awk '{print $5}'
```

Or even better us to use stat command like this (On Mac):

```
stat -f "%z" yourFile
```

Or (on Linux)

```
stat -c "%s" yourFile
```

that will output size of file in bytes.